# Unable to access keytool alias with unicode characters in name

Tags: java, unicode, keytool

I want to get an md5 with keytool for the Google Maps API but I'm getting an error. When I try to run:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -alias arabamı bulalım -keystore "c:\key.keystore"
```

keytool returns an error stating:

```
Illegal error: bulal2m
```

I think the error is being caused by the Unicode [dotless I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) ("ı") character in my alias name, `arabamı bulalım`. How can I work around this?

Comment: How is this an Android issue? Is this so you can develop something with the Google Maps API?

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.exe` which you appear to be using to call `keytool` does not use `utf-8`. You are entering characters in another (locale-specific) encoding. You can check it by running `chcp` from command line.

The solution would be to:

- run cygwin/bash (which uses `utf-8`)
- try write some Java code (and hardcode the alias name in an `utf-8` encoded `.java` file)
- try chanding cmd.exe code-page to `utf-8` with `chcp 65001` (but it rarely ever works).

Answer (score 0):

ok for the md5 ı used jre6 and it solved :) C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin>keytool -list -alias "arabamı bulalım" -keystore "c:\key.keystore" Thank you all my friend